# Почему можно изменять члены класса в константных функциях?

Tags: c++, классы, const, дизайн-языка

Почему этот код компилируется, т.е. почему можно изменять члены в константных функциях? Ведь это предотвращает кучу оптимизаций, связанных с константностью.

```cpp
struct A {
    int x = 42;
    int* y = &x;
    constexpr int foo() const {
        return ++(*y);
    }
};
static_assert(A{}.foo() == 43);
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145939/discussion-on-question-by-nikita-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё из-за косвенности. Вы разыменовываете указатель, а разыменование не является модификацией. При этом компилятор не будет проверять на что он указывает. Так что это, можно сказать, такой хак. А вообще, для таких случаев есть ключевое слово `mutable`.

Что касается опитимизаций. В *абстрактной машине* `C++` есть такое понятие как *[не]наблюдаемое поведение*. Всё, что вы не можете наблюдать, может быть оптимизировано по усмотрению компилятора (его разработчиков). Для предотвращения некоторых таких оптимизаций даже было введено ключевое слово `volatile`.

Comment: Имелось в виду, что компилятор и разработчик хотели бы сделать оптимизацию, т.к. данные константные, но компилятор не может этого сделать, т.к. `const` не гарантирует константность, как показано в примере

Comment: @Nikita, бессмысленно обсуждать какие-то абстрактные оптимизации в вакууме. О том какие оптимизации есть и в каких случаях они работают знают по большей части только сами разработчики компиляторов. Лишь немногие оптимизации стали частью стандарта, типа `EBO`, `[N]RVO` и т.п.

Comment: @Nikita, какие оптимизации, связанные с константностью вы знаете? Константность по большей части нужна лишь для перегрузок и для проверки корректности кода.

Comment: Короче говоря, вопрос скорее про то, почему `const` это не `__attribute__(const)`; почему такое поведение допустимо в принципе. Добавил метку [tag:дизайн-языка], чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: @Nikita, очевидно потому, что компилятор не проверяет в компилтайме на что указывает ваш указатель.

Comment: @Nikita, и даже если бы он проверял. Где гарантия того, что в рантайме ваш указатель не станет указывать на член `A`?

Comment: @Nikita, разработчики компиляторов не идиоты, они на таких вещах, как говориться, собаку съели. И прекрасно знают где, что и как можно и нельзя оптимизировать.

Comment: "предотвращения некоторых таких оптимизаций даже было введено ключевое слово volatile" - эта часть кстати тоже неверная

Comment: @user7860670, `volatile` нужен для того, чтобы компилятор не делал опасных оптимизаций. Всё верно.

Comment: @user7860670 а для чего оно было введено?